# Data Science Case Study

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science

Please help me to get the right answer of the below question, which is asked in one of the interview.

There is a bank, no of users visit bank for different- different services, but most of the users give bad rating and goes unsatisfied. What should bank do identify the reasons for the bad ratings. Bank capture data like, user info, agent info who deals with users, services offered, and no if things.

1. How to identify rules or reasons which are playing an important role in bad rating using machine learning techniques only.
2. If we build a classification model, that a user will be unsatisfied/satisfied. Then let say we get list of users who will be unsatisfied. Now what should we do with this data of unsatisfied users to help bank improve rating and business.

Comment: For this scenario, you might want to collect some data from the users. First, every user needs to rate every service of the bank in a definite range ( 1 - 5 ). Then, we calculate the maximum negative ratings and to which service are they given. This service will be one of which the bank has to make higher improvements. Then, we need to calculate the similarity of this ratings with ratings of other services. They service which is the most similar has a negative rating like the earlier one. This becomes the second service which is to be improved.

Comment: How can we identify multiple reasons using tree models? this is something I could not answer.

Answer (score 1):

Train a classifier to predict dissatisfaction.

Don't use a neutral network, but something **interpretable**.

Then interpret the model for **feature importance**.

A good choice would be a random forest.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your unsatisfied customer dataset has information about reason of dissatisfaction along with other attributes like user details,age,region and services they avail from bank.In this case there might be the case that one more more ML models and algorithm might need to be trained and optimised to get accurate picture.However critical factors to look for would be Services they are associated with,Reason of dissatisfaction and might be agent they are mapped to.
Above mentioned 3 key attributes can be executed with regression models to get prediction and improvement plan.Please note selection of ML models also depend upon detail analysis of dataset and asking and deriving right question from stakeholders.

Comment: We are not having a reason for dissatisfaction, this is something which we want to identify, we are only having ratings given by users and other details of the users like salary age education, etc. we want to identify the reasons  or rules which are playing an important role in bad ratings and there is not only service but no of features in dataset.

Comment: ok.In this case ratings (which is bad ) in case is the factor.as I have noticed you might be having some corellation on these ratings with agents,services and features associated with users.Is that right? so In my view mapping data mapping could be something like this,  User--> agents->services->features->rating. If this could be the high level data set you can run ML models on this.

Answer (score 0):

For this question they may be looking for feature importance. Hence, interpretable algorithms are preferred. You may use logistic regression to find the top coefficients or a tree-based ensemble method such as random forests or gradient boosting. The top features will denote the features driving the model's decisions. Shap values are also something to look at.

Sources: An Introduction to Statistical Learning With Applications in R, AceAI Prep, Andrew Ng courses.